# How can I find the result of a Bool ArrayList comparing its Bool values?

Tags: c#, arraylist, boolean, boolean-logic

If I have an `ArrayList`  include `boolean` values, what is the best way to find out the result of this sequence of Bool values ?

I was trying something like this

```
bool result = false;    
bool flag = false;
ArrayList flags = new ArrayList();

if (something > 5)
{
 flag = true;
}
flags.Add(flag);    

foreach (bool val in flags)
{
      result &= val;
}
```

However if I would declare the result variable as true instead of false, then this changes the result. I am a bit confused.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Um... what are you ***actually*** trying to do? Sure, if you change your code, the result changes, but what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: It's beter to replace ArrayList to List<bool>

Comment: `myArrayList.Cast<bool>().All(x=>x)` will tell you if all the bools in your sequence are true. Why are you using `ArrayList` instead of `List<bool>`?

Comment: I am trying to find out if the result of this Bool sequence using & operator is true or false: e.g If I have in my ArrayList (false,false,true) then the result is False!

Comment: Ok I will use List<bool> and I will tell you

Comment: Thank you Gabba and Spender so much, finally I used List<bool> and the trick with Cast<bool>().All(x=>x) and it works :) thnx again!

Comment: If you use a `List<bool>` instead of `ArrayList` then no need to `.Cast<bool>()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using &= then the initial value  of "result" is very important. If result starts as false, however many times you do &= the result will stay false. If result starts as true, then &= will behave as you expect

Answer (score 1):

Change from `ArrayList` to `List<bool>` and try it using recursion. you dont need the extra bool variable.

```
  public bool BoolVal(List<bool> list, int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)//The condition that limites the method for calling itself
            return list[n];
        return list[n] & BoolVal(list, n - 1);
    }
```

call it like

```
var result = BoolVal(flags, flags.Count -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use a strong type, ex `List<bool>`, instead of `ArrayList`.

Then use extension `All` method to check if all if `true`

```
List<bool> flags = new List<bool>();
...
bool restul = flags.All(flag => flag);
```

Or:

```
bool restul = !flags.Any(flag => flag);
```

Comment: thank you , I found similar solution to my problem from above suggestions, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to mark your  answer as correct :p

Answer (score 0):

```
flags.ToArray().Where(item => (bool)item == true).SingleOrDefault() != null
```

This works for me if you can use LINQ if not then I would suggest that you default result to false and exit out the loop when you find true (after setting result to true something like):

```
foreach (bool val in flags)
{
      if(val)
      {
          result = true;
          break;
      }

}
```

Also are bools the only thing in the ArrayList ??

The other suggestions here are good as well but again use LINQ.